# jQuery. Перезагрузка события

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть событие:

```
$('#fun').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Какой-то код
});
```

И программный вызов `$('#fun').click()` не срабатывает. Как можно перезагрузить событие

P.S. Программный клик вызывается после клика пользователя, т.е. это уже второй клик. Как-то нужно отменить `e.preventDefault()`, спустя определенное время. Клик не срабатывает на второй раз

Comment: Вы до этого уже вызывали этот код?

Comment: добавьте [mcve], ну все что угодно может быть, может вы jQuery не подключили, может такого ид нету, хотя бы, что в консоли пишет напишите

Comment: @DaemonHK, простите, добавил правку

Comment: @zakiroof замените `// какой-то код` на `alert("test");`, и Вы увидите, что все работает

Comment: @zakiroof если вам не помог ни один из советов, то оберните ваш вызов в функцию, вызовите ее в нужном месте, а потом второй раз при перегрузке контейнера (не страницы)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю что вам в вашем коде мешает. Но вот посмотрите нормально все работает. Дело не в методе `jquery`. А в вашем коде.

```js
$('#fun').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).text());
});

$('.old').click(function(){
  $('#fun').click();
});
```

```css
div,span{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="fun">Click Span</span>

<div class="old">Click to the span</div>
```